# How to prevent serializing null values using kotlin serialization

Tags: kotlin, serialization, json-deserialization

I'm using `kotlinx-serialization-json`

I have this class:

```
@Serializable
data class Event(
    @SerialName("temperature") val temperature: Float?,
    @SerialName("pressure") val pressure: Float?,
    @SerialName("humidity") val humidity: Float?,
)
```

and this call

```
Json.encodeToString(Event(temperature = 42.0f, pressure = null, humidity = 20.9f))
```

During serialization I receive such json:

```
{
    "temperature": 20.5,
    "pressure": null,
    "humidity": 20.9
}
```

but I would like to prevent serializing null values and receive this:

```
{
    "temperature": 20.5,
    "humidity": 20.9
}
```

It's a problem for me, because during serializing lengthy list of events I waste a lot of lines. Anyone's got an idea how to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

There is new simple way to achieve this:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/09/kotlinx-serialization-1-3-released/#excluding-nulls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ignore all defaults and do something like this:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Event(
    @SerialName("temperature") val temperature: Float?,
    @SerialName("pressure") val pressure: Float? = null,
    @SerialName("humidity") val humidity: Float?,
)

    val jsonMapper = Json { encodeDefaults = false}
    val body = jsonMapper.encodeToString(Event(temperature = 42.0f,pressure = null, humidity = 20.9f))
```

Please, be aware of that, in the above case you are ignoring ALL defaults.
If you want to ignore only null values you have to implement a custom serializer.

For this example custom serializer will look like this:

```kotlin
object EventSerializer: KSerializer<Event> {
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Event {
        decoder.decodeStructure(descriptor) {
            var temperature: Float? = null
            var humidity:Float? = null
            var pressure: Float? = null

            while (true) {
                when (val index = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)) {
                    0 -> temperature = decodeFloatElement(descriptor, 0)
                    1 -> pressure = decodeFloatElement(descriptor, 1)
                    2 -> humidity = decodeFloatElement(descriptor, 2)
                    CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE -> break
                    else -> error("Unexpected index: $index")
                }
            }
           return Event(temperature, pressure, humidity)
        }
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Event) {
        encoder.beginStructure(descriptor).run {
            value.temperature?.let { encodeStringElement(descriptor, 0, it.toString()) }
            value.pressure?.let { encodeStringElement(descriptor, 1, it.toString()) }
            value.humidity?.let { encodeStringElement(descriptor, 2, it.toString()) }
            endStructure(descriptor)
        }
    }

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor("Event") {
        element<String>("temperature")
        element<String>("pressure")
        element<String>("humidity")

    }
}
```

To use it -> `@Serializable(with = EventSerializer::class)`

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll decide to go with `encodeDefaults = false` as a project-level design decision

Comment: val json = Json {
                encodeDefaults = true
                explicitNulls = false
            }